# draw a single pixel in the screen

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, drawing

I need to know what is the method that draw pixel, in what Libarary can I find it and how to use it?

I search the internet for that and I found:

1. A method called `putpixel()` in the C language in `Graphics.h`

   but I have Microsoft Visual Stdio which has no `Graphics.h`

   I even downloaded turbo c++ many times(which has the Graphics.h header file) but I couldn't install it in my PC (I am using Wondows 7 64 bit system).
2. A method called `Setpixel()` in `windows.h` header file but I could know how to use it.

   using `Setpixel()` `GetPixel` I managed to draw a red pixel in the screen but the program is not stable each time I execute it:

   1. the pixel don't appear in the same location.
   2. disappear after a litle time.
   3. don't apper at all.

so what to do??

Comment: Perhaps you should read up about the Windows graphics API, because what you're trying to use is ancient/dead history.

Comment: You really need a book on Windows programming (E.g., *Windows Via C/C++*, by Jeffrey Richter). Unfortunately, getting started is surprisingly large amount of work (or at least a lot of code). VC++ will generate a do-nothing program for you though, which pre-generates most of that code.

Comment: Besides GDI there's also DirectX.

Comment: [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is even better; you can use DirectX or OpenGL without much hassle, so you can use it with VC++, CodeBlocks or whatever. At my graphics programming class in college, that's what we used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

....

```
putchar(".");
fflush(stdout);
```

Should do the trick.